# Seagate Barracuda SSD HD password fails when moving drive to new machine

Tags: hard-drive, passwords

I have a Seagate Barracuda SATA SSD circa 2019 . It has been in a laptop with laptop startup password and disk access password.

Laptop has now died so I have moved the physical disk to a new (rather, old) ACER laptop.

The ACER laptop recognises the drive and asked for the unlock password.

I keep entering the password that has always worked but the ACER laptop always says it's failed.

I am CERTAIN the password is correct. Password is alphanumeric Latin only.

Is there something I am missing or can I somehow establish this is an error with the ACER computer?

The ACER interface states: "Seagate Barracuda SSLock "

## UPDATE

Per suggestion from comments I am unable to pad the password with space at the point of entry.

ACER only accepts 12 characters for password in total.

Comment: The thing is BIOSes / UEFI firmwares does not always set the ATA password with the verbatim input from you, and they don't all process the input the same way AFAIK. One thing you can try is pad the password input with spaces until the length is 32 bytes / characters. (Or in case it's this new laptop that internally pads the input with spaces, you may want to try unlock it with `hdparm` on Linux without any padding.)

Comment: @TomYan yes that's what I'm thinking from researching similar topics, but I have no idea to know how to correctly pad the password; the ACER screen only allows me up to I think 12 or 14 characters.

Comment: @TomYan I have read about hdparm but I have no running computer to operate from... Chicken and egg situation....

Comment: @Broken_M A Linux Live USB should be sufficient. In emergencies I've (sometimes successful, sometimes not) used drivedroid to boot an ISO from an android phone